# How to avoid multiple http access to a wave resource file from a java program?

Tags: java, http, inputstream, wav, javasound

I used the following code to get the data from a wav file on a web server.  The `getFormat()`, `getFormatLength()`, `totallength` and reading the bytes, each performed an http access and the server log showed that there are 3 accesses.  Is there a way to make it one trip?

```
try {
    audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);//soundFile);
    format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
    totallength = audioInputStream.getFrameLength()*format.getFrameSize();
    waveData = new byte[(int)totallength];
    int total=0;
    int nBytesRead = 0;
    try {
        while (nBytesRead != -1 && total<totallength) {
            nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(waveData, total, (int) totallength);
            if (nBytesRead>0)
                total+=nBytesRead;
            }
    ...
```

Comment: Are all of those fullworthy GET requests (which returns the entire file in the response body), or are the first few on `getFormat()` and `getFormatLength()` HEAD requests (which returns only the HTTP headers and thus an empty response body). I'd expect them to be "just" HEAD requests which are supposed to be really cheap. Or, is the server maintained by yourself (e.g. a servlet?) and is it not doing its job entirely right and returning the whole file on a HEAD as well?

Comment: @BalusC I used a servlt and I think I need to update that code.  But I was also thinking just use the suggestion from Joop Eggen that just read the whole stream without knowing the size at first.  I realized the Format is not used.  This way can reduce the round trip time as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it looks that you are reading first the entire file, into memory, why not reading reading all first in.

```
    // Read the audio file into waveData:
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for (;;) {
        int b = in.read();
        if (b == -1) {
            break;
        }
        bos.write(b);
    }
    in.close();
    bos.close();
    byte[] waveData = bos.toByteArray();

    // Create the AudioInputSteam:
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(waveData);
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bis);
```

Comment: Reading it byte-by-byte would be very slow, from memory.

Comment: The only mod is to use a buffer instead of read byte-by-byte.  But this method worked!